# Understanding memory access in C++ with placement new

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

currently learning about C++ and I'm revisiting a small memory manager our prof has partly written as an exercise and since I have ignored my C++ skills for far too long, I'm having trouble understanding how memory and placement new actually works. So basically I have multiple Bucket objects that all hold a certain amount of chunks and each chunk can have a certain amount of memory. A BucketAdmin class has all those Bucket objects.

```
BucketAdmin::BucketAdmin(void)
{
m_baseMemory = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(malloc(sizeof(Bucket) * NUM_OF_BUCKETS) );

Bucket* base_pointer = reinterpret_cast<Bucket*>(m_baseMemory);
std::cout << &base_pointer<< "     "  <<  &base_pointer + sizeof(Bucket) *     NUM_OF_BUCKETS  << "     " << sizeof(Bucket) * NUM_OF_BUCKETS << std::endl;

for (unsigned short i = 0; i < NUM_OF_BUCKETS; i++)
{
    m_buckets[i] = new (&base_pointer[i])Bucket(m_bucketSizes[i], BUCKET_CAPACITY/m_bucketSizes[i]);
}
}
```

So this code right here is confusing me. A Bucket is 16 Bytes in size (as stated by sizeof(Bucket) and the number of buckets is 5. That means that the m_baseMemory allocates 80 bytes of ram and is a char pointer (how that reinterpret_cast work exactly and why is it used twice?). Next, a bucket pointer is created by casting the memory adress from before to a Bucket pointer - how and why exactly is that? When I output both adresses, they are very different from each other. The way I understand the first two lines is that 80 bytes of memory are allocated, whose adress is saved in m_baseMemory. Then, because we want to construct Bucket objects, that pointer is cast to a Bucket pointer, so that we can iterate through the Bucket-adresses in the for-loop (basically one i is an offset of i*sizeof(Bucket), so i*16, correct?) without specifically stating the offset required for each Bucket object.

So, as placement new is being used at the position &base_pointer[i], shouldn't they be the same? I don't understand how the two kinds of memory adresses (m_baseMemory, base_pointer) are so vastly different from each other. When I compare the base_pointer adress with the base_pointer adress plus the allocated memory, I should get an adress that is 80 bigger (in decimal), yet when I compare the numbers it's a difference of multiple hundreds? An example:
The base_pointer adress is: 010FFA6C
The base_pointer adress + sizeof(Bucket) * NUM_OF_BUCKETS is: 010FFBAC

Even if sizeof(Bucket) * NUM_OF_BUCKETS = 80 would be interpreted as hex, it would add 128 (8*16), not 320 as is the case here. I honestly don't understand how this is calculated, so help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: alignment requirements maybe? `Bucket` needs alignment whereas `char` doesn't.

Comment: 16 bytes? Are you sure it's not 16 bits (2 bytes), cuz that would make whole lot of sense more ?

Comment: @TomaszPlaskota sizeof returns 16, so I guess that means 16 bytes, no?

Comment: It sounds like you don't understand the difference between pointers to different types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main source of confusion is that you're looking at the address of `base_pointer` when you should be looking at its value.

Another thing you seem to have missed is that adding `k` to a pointer adds `k + sizeof(what the pointer points to)` to the address.

`&base_pointer` is the address of your variable, not of the allocated memory, so `&base_pointer + sizeof(Bucket) * NUM_OF_BUCKETS` is an address `80 * sizeof(Bucket*)` bytes away from it.
And `80 * sizeof(Bucket*)` is 320 on a 32-bit target.

The address you're interested in is `base_pointer`; `m_baseMemory + k * sizeof(Bucket)` and `base_pointer + k` denote the same address, and so does `&base_pointer[k]`.

Comment: Thank you, that gave me some information.
But why are m_baseMemory and base_pointer still so different? I guess it has something to do with the cast to a Bucket pointer, but how exactly does it work? I mean, it can't just divide the adress by the size of the Bucket or something similar, as that would change the adress completely.

Comment: Also, if I output m_baseMemory (it's a char pointer, type char *) I get weird symbols, not an adress. What's up with that? Shouldn't it work just like base_pointer, both of them pointing to roughly the same adress?

Comment: @Grougal Tried to clarify. (Cast a pointer to `void*` if you want to print it.)